# How to sum and push unique items in a array

Tags: javascript

I have list of fruits

```
let fruits = [ 0: 
                  name: banana
                  rotten: 1
                  fresh: 0
               1: 
                 name: apple
                 rotten: 0
                 fresh: 1
               2: 
                 name: banana
                 rotten: 1
                 fresh: 0
               3: 
                 name: apple
                 rotten: 1
                 fresh: 0
             ]
```

I want to push it in a new list so I get this desired outcome:

```
0:
  name: banana
  rotten: 2
  fresh: 0
1:
 name: apple
 rotten: 1
 fresh: 1
```

How can I achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Create new, empty array. Then traverse through the existing array and for every item check if given name already exists in the new array. If not, create it. If yes, just add the rotten and fresh counts.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Clone a existing array? your fruits array, and your desired outcome looks the same.

Comment: In the first array the entries appears 2 times in the list.
In the second array it shows banana and apple once and sums up rotten and fresh for each fruit.

Comment: I have tried with:
```
let result = []
for (let i in fruits) {
  if (result.indexOf(fruis[i].name) === -1) {
     result.push(fruits[i].name)
   }
}
```
Then I get a new array with:
0: banana
1: apple

but i also want the sums of rotten and fresh like this:
 0:
    name: banana
    rotten: 2
    fresh: 0
1:
   name: apple
   rotten: 1
   fresh: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `.reduce` you can do the job

You can take an example on that snippet

```
let fruits = [ { 
                  name: "banana",
                  rotten: 1,
                  fresh: 0
               },
               { 
                 name: "apple",
                 rotten: 0,
                 fresh: 1
               },
               { 
                 name: "banana",
                 rotten: 1,
                 fresh: 0
               },
               { 
                 name: "apple",
                 rotten: 1,
                 fresh: 0
               }
             ];

const result = fruits.reduce( (acc, val) => {
const ind = acc.findIndex( (element) => element.name === val.name);  
  if (ind != -1) {
  
    acc[ind] = {...acc[ind], rotten: acc[ind].rotten + val.rotten, fresh: acc[ind].fresh + val.fresh};
    
    return acc;
  }
  
  return [...acc, val ];

}, []);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!
It solved my problem :)